# ActiveSync port ipad

Tags: activesync

I want to use ActiveSync inside a firewall from iPad. What port does ActiveSync communicate on? Which ports do I have to keep open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ll need HTTPS (443). No other ports are needed.

Comment: Does even the mail transfer happen over 443?

Comment: it may well just need 443 — I’m not 100% sure, though, sorry.

Comment: Yes, everything ocurrs over port 443. No other ports are required.

Answer (score 3):

If Exchange is configured correctly, you should only need port 443 open on your firewall.